# Are my connections being returned to the pool if I don't Dispose my IDataReader?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net, connection-pooling

I'm trying to determine if there are glaring errors in a code base, or not.

The code in question calls a third party dll which returns an IDataReader.  If the code uses the reader without disposing of it, it won't be explicitly returned to the pool, correct?

Here's the calling code:

```
IDataReader rdr = db.ExecSPGetDataReader("dbo.someStoredProcedure", paramList);
if (rdr.Read())
{
    List<nameValuePair> formValues = Utils.nameValuePairs(rdr["valuepairs"].ToString());
    foreach (nameValuePair nvp in formValues)
    {
        if (nvp.name.ToLower() == "name")
        {
            outString = nvp.value;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the decompiled third party dll code:

```
    public IDataReader ExecSPGetDataReader(string sp, List<param> paramList)
    {
        IDataReader dataReader;
        using (DbCommand dbC = this.setDBCommand(sp, paramList, true))
        {
            IDataReader dr = this._db.ExecuteReader(dbC);
            this.setOutputParams(dbC, paramList);
            dataReader = dr;
        }
        return dataReader;
    }
```

It looks like the command gets disposed of, probably for the purpose of disposing the connection, but if that's true, how can anything be read from the returned IDataReader?

Comment: Is it necessary to retain the `DbCommand` for the returned `IDataReader` to work correctly?

Comment: Just a side note - exposing bare data readers is a horrible design. I don't envy you. At least make sure you dispose them after you are done reading data.

Comment: @spender That's the question that I had.  What I'm thinking is that the IDataReader hangs on to the database connection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If the code uses the reader without disposing of it, it won't be explicitly returned to the pool, correct?

That is correct. Change the code to this:

```
using (IDataReader rdr =
    db.ExecSPGetDataReader("dbo.someStoredProcedure", paramList))
{
    if (rdr.Read())
    {
        List<nameValuePair> formValues =
            Utils.nameValuePairs(rdr["valuepairs"].ToString());
        foreach (nameValuePair nvp in formValues)
        {
            if (nvp.name.ToLower() == "name")
            {
                outString = nvp.value;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `using` statement will ensure that `Dispose` is called.

Comment: Thanks Michael.  I was seeing the # of connection rise sharply, then fall later.  I'm guessing the connections were just hanging around long enough not being used to get returned to the pool.